# Same connection, tables with same name in different schemas. How to force Datagrip to include database name?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, jetbrains-ide, amazon-athena, datagrip

I have a Data Source connection with two catalogs.
These two catalogs have the same schema names, and these also with the same table names.

- DS connection

  - catalog1

    - schemaA

      - tableX
    - schemaB

      - tableY
      - tableZ
  - catalog2

    - schemaA

      - tableX
    - schemaB

      - tableY
      - tableZ

In the *[Query Console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/query-console.html)* if I query the same table name from both catalogs I do manually something like this *(notice the catalog1 and catalog2 usage)* :

```
select count(*) from catalog1.schemaA.tableX
        
select count(*) from catalog2.schemaA.tableX
```

But doing it within the Data Editor (GUI) **I got the same results, which I should not** .
The issue is that I do not know if there is a way to force Datagrip to use the catalog name too in the queries executed using the Data Editor.

[image: Count directly from the Data Editor]

The [view query feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/table-editor.html#186396) shows the query is run only from the schema name, without the catalog name.

```
select count(*) from schemaA.tableX
```

[image: view query description from jetbrains datagrip page]

*Further information for context:*

- The used driver is [AthenaJDBC42_preview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) v11.preview, it is the same with v13. v14 is buggy.
- The two databases/catalogs are from different AWS accounts using this [Cross-account AWS Glue Data Catalog access with Amazon Athena lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/cross-account-aws-glue-data-catalog-access-with-amazon-athena/)

---

Update some hours later

I found the following in the [Simba Athena JDBC Driver  Installation and Configuration Guide](https://athena-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/drivers/JDBC/athena-preview/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.11_preview/docs/Simba+Athena+JDBC+Driver+Install+and+Configuration+Guide.pdf) :

> The Simba Athena JDBC Driver provides access to all the catalogs and databases
> that are available on the Athena server, ...

> Amazon Athena provides catalogs that enable you to access the data source that is
> being queried. These catalogs contain databases, which correspond to
> JDBC schemas, and each database contains data that has been organized into tables.
> By default, if your query statement does not specify a catalog, the driver queries the
> data under the catalog named AwsDataCatalog.

So, the Data Editor should use the catalog name when executing queries.
I don't know if is a bug into Datagrip or in the Simba Athena Driver.

Comment: Am I right that in the data editor you see the correct data, you just want the database name to be in the query?

Comment: No, I do not :-( 
One catalog/database is from production account and the other one from development. I have different amount of data in both but when running the query from the Data Editor I get the same data (same count for example)

Comment: So, you just double-click on ONE table and see the data from THE OTHER ONE?

Comment: Exactly, double-click or F4, even if the path (above the tabs) says is the good catalog-schema-table. Please give a look at the little update I did yesterday on the description, the issue comes from the default catalog (AwsDataCatalog) if no one is specified.

Comment: Gotcha! We'll answer you in the ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11277